# An user control as Tool tip for WPF TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, tooltip

I have a TextBlock having a canvas as its `ToolTip`. An user control is bounded to the canvas from the back-end in constructor. The TextBlock defined in xaml as follows:

```
<TextBlock Width="60" Height="40" Text="More info.">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <Canvas Name="canToolTip"></Canvas> 
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

The constructor definition will be :

```
 public UC_PublicationAdd()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // assign datacontext
        canToolTip.Children.Add(new ToolTipControl());
    }
```

The whole scenario is fine Now let me come to the Problem. When i place the mouse over the `TextBlock` ToolTip is showing but its size is not controllable. What i mean is that, size of tooltip is too smaller(default size when tooltip text is not present). I want the tooltip equal to the size of the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for Make you Confused, finally i solved the issue by assigning width and height to the canvas inside the tooltip. The xaml looks like the following:

```
<TextBlock Width="60" Height="40" Text="More info.">
       <TextBlock.ToolTip>
          <Canvas Name="canToolTip" Height="80" Width="130"></Canvas> 
       </TextBlock.ToolTip> 
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Why not accept your answer? .By the way, you use `xamal` instead of `xaml` (two times on this page)

Comment: @Sakura: Thank you i have corrected that. I have to wait for two days to mark it as accepted